# Sharepoint Access App - How to look up a field in another table and return the value

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint

We are using sharepoint access app for inventory and struggling with lookup value. What we are trying to do is:

Table A
Staff Name
Desktop Name (same as table B's Desktop Name)

Table B
Desktop Name (same as table A's Desktop Name)
Assignee

Whenever we enter data in Table A with staff name and desktop name, we want to return the staff name in Table B's assignee field.

Staff Name = Assignee 
**Using the Desktop Name as key

If you can provide me with any tip to make it work, that would be much appreciated!!!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return these in the datasheet view.

When editing the datasheet view in access, on the right hand side in the Field List at the bottom are a list of your other tables.
Click the Plus next to Table B and drag Assignee in to your datasheet. This will bring up a prompt to select the relationship, you can then choose Desktop Name for both tables, and select the way they correspond, I would assume many records in Table A correspond to one record in Table B.